# How do I get the current version of my installed mapbox SDK programmatically?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I found within MapBox.h these lines:

```
/// Project version number for Mapbox.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT MGL_EXPORT double MapboxVersionNumber;

/// Project version string for Mapbox.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT MGL_EXPORT const unsigned char MapboxVersionString[];
```

Those appear to be global exports, and I can access them within my code anywhere with `MapboxVersionNumber` and `MapboxVersionString`. However, they're both a 5 digit number (or 6 digits if you count the `.0` on the double). I was looking for something more like `4.0.1`

Answer (score 3):

You can extract information from the Mapbox Info.plist file by creating a `Bundle` instance initialised with a given identifier

In Swift 4.2 you can try this:

```
extension Bundle {

    var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
        // Actually retrieves the information from the plist.
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }

    var buildVersionNumber: String? {
        // Actually retrieves the information from the plist.
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }

    static var mapbox: Bundle {
        // Crash can occur if you are not linking Mapbox and "com.mapbox.sdk.ios" does not exist.
        return Bundle.init(identifier: "com.mapbox.sdk.ios")!
    }
}
```

Then you can use this anywhere in your project:

```
let mapboxVersion = Bundle.mapbox.releaseVersionNumber
print("Mapbox version: \(mapboxVersion)")
```

---

**Note**: If somehow Mapbox decides to change its identifier string, or if you want to do the same for another framework, you can print all the existing embed frameworks:

```
for frameworkBundle in Bundle.allFrameworks {
    print("Framework bundle identifier: \(frameworkBundle.bundleIdentifier ?? "No identifier")")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the debugger, get the list of all frameworks by adding a new expression:

```
NSBundle.allFrameworks
```

Expand the results. With "Filter" in the lower right corner you can search for the term "mapbox". Once you identified the framework, you can reference it with its address by copying it to a new expression, and query for the strings like this:

```
[(NSBundle *)0x00000002802f8730 objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Checking today for macos SDK the bundle identifier was "com.mapbox.Mapbox".